# Como desabilitar o resize do textarea?

Tags: html, css

Como desabilito o `resize` de um `textarea` ?

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Gostaria que não desse para alterar o tamanho da caixa...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `resize` para definir isso.

Para desabilitar a alteração do tamanho da `textarea` você define esse valor para `none`:

```html
<textarea style="resize: none"></textarea>
```

Ainda há uma maneira de limitar o `resize` em apenas uma direção (ou vertical, ou horizontal).

Exemplos:

Somente Vertical:

```html
<textarea style="resize: vertical"></textarea>
```

Somente: Horizontal:

```html
<textarea style="resize: horizontal"></textarea>
```

Comment: A título de curiosidade: para redimensionar os dois lados, use `resize: both`

Answer (score 14):

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 9):

Setando a priopriedade `resize` para `none`.

Ex.: (Todos os `TextArea`)

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Ex.: Definindo por classe

```css
.resize-none {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="resize-none"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

A propriedade `resize` controla como um elemento pode ser redimensionado pelo usuário clicando e arrastando o canto inferior direito do elemento.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('p').css('resize', $(this).text());
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1D1F1F;
}

section { 
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5em;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <button>both</button>
  <button>horizontal</button>
  <button>vertical</button>
  <button>none</button>
<p class="resize">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue. In sed dui placerat nisl cursus aliquet. Integer nisl lorem, maximus et viverra non, aliquet vel arcu. Cras ullamcorper, arcu id molestie scelerisque, est turpis interdum mauris, sit amet pretium mi lectus at metus. Phasellus ornare odio in ipsum faucibus, et tempus est porttitor. Nullam sollicitudin eleifend mi at semper. Vivamus vel neque nec magna lacinia commodo in vel ante. Aliquam tincidunt, purus sit amet congue placerat, lacus mauris rhoncus nisl, nec ornare libero purus eget augue.</p>
</section>
```

Veja mais detalhes aqui [neste artigo](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Outra resposta praticamente igual... com jQuery ainda.

Comment: @DiegoSouza o jquery é só para ver funcionando em tempo real. Você tentou executar?

Comment: Sim. Não funciona.

Comment: @DiegoSouza como não?! Funciona perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: @MagicHat então, coloquei o jQuery só para melhor visualizar, para poder executar e ver em tempo real funcionado com snippet. Nesse trecho `$('p').css('resize', $(this).text())` está sendo alterado o atributo do `textarea` na media em que você clica nos botões,(both, horizontal, vertical e none);

Comment: @MagicHat não sei porque raios, mas aqui funciona e funcionará também o uso das propriedades (both, horizontal, vertical e none) na prática, porque querendo ou não, a resposta se assemelha (indiferente) com outras desta sua questão, porém mostrando os 4 casos no snippet. ^^