# Como posso desativar a área redimensionável de um textbox?

Tags: html, css

Não sou entusiasta de linguagens front-end, mas num dos exemplos que estava testando, fiquei na dúvida em como desativar a propriedade redimensionável de uma área de texto.

Sei que posso redimensionar uma área de texto clicando em seu canto inferior e ir arrastando com o mouse, mas não quero permitir.

A pergunta é, como posso desativá-la?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como desabilitar o resize do textarea?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177917/como-desabilitar-o-resize-do-textarea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, você pode fazer isso através de css:

```
<textarea style="resize:none" name="name"></textarea>
```

Ou então algo como:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Opa amigo!

Você pode "desativar" esse modo redimencionável, limitando sua textbox ao tamanho que deseja, exemplo:

```
textarea {max-width:100px; max-height:100px;}
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida pergunte!